# How to resolve dart version conflicts

Tags: dart, homebrew

I have a problem while compiling my code and i run : brew  info dart
I get the following message :

```
brew info dart
==> dart-lang/dart/dart: stable 3.1.5, HEAD
SDK
https://dart.dev
Conflicts with:
  dart-beta (because dart-beta ships the same binaries)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dart/2.19.4 (1,039 files, 612.5MB) *
  Built from source on 2023-03-21 at 14:08:54
From: https://github.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart/blob/HEAD/Formula/dart.rb
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
Please note the path to the Dart SDK:
  /opt/homebrew/opt/dart/libexec
```

How to resolve the conflicts please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me I tried this and it worked:

Uninstall dart:
`brew uninstall dart dart-beta`

brew cleanup:
`brew cleanup`

Reinstall dart:
`brew install dart`